# Oracle sub-query on JOIN throwing unexpected identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm building an Oracle application for my University assignment, and I'm experiencing some very strange behaviour when I try to perform a subquery to return a further column to allow me to SELECT a DISTINCT store, without getting its image.

The reason I need to do this is because my Image is required to be stored in BLOB format (due to the assignment spec), therefore I wish to first SELECT the unique store item, and then pull back the associated BLOB thumbnail for that store.

My approach below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        stores.store_id,
        stores.name,
        stores.description,
        stores.postcode
     FROM stores
     INNER JOIN 
     (
           SELECT
           dbms_lob.getlength(store_images.thumbnail) AS thumbnail
           FROM store_images
     ) store_images ON stores.store_id = store_images.store_id
WHERE stores.store_id = 2;
```

To me, everything looks fine however I get the error

`ORA-00904: "STORE_IMAGES"."STORE_ID": invalid identifier`

I know what this error means, but in the context of my problem it makes little sense to me, I've triple checked the schema and the Foreign and Primary key names match identically.

If I remove the sub-query component, the query compiles fine.  What is the issue here?

Comment: Should you include `store_id` in the subselect statement? You are trying to match on a field that you haven't included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pull out store_images.store_id in your inline-view:

```
INNER JOIN 
     (
           SELECT
           dbms_lob.getlength(store_images.thumbnail) AS thumbnail,
           store_images.store_id
           FROM store_images
     ) store_images ON stores.store_id = store_images.store_id
```

Incidentally, since you're not selecting from your inline view, your statement could be shortened to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        stores.store_id,
        stores.name,
        stores.description,
        stores.postcode
FROM stores
INNER JOIN store_images 
ON stores.store_id = store_images.store_id 
AND stores.store_id = 2;
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle APEX to build my application, and I require the thumbnail field to build my form, therefore I cannot shorten it to that.   If I don't do the sub-query, APEX throws an error as it cannot do a DISTINCT select when there is BLOB data present in the top level query

Comment: OK but the query you present in your question doesn't select the BLOB, so that one could be shortened. Does my first suggestion work?

Comment: Yes, your first solution fixed my problem - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        stores.store_id,
        stores.name,
        stores.description,
        stores.postcode,
        dbms_lob.getlength(store_images.thumbnail) AS thumbnail
FROM stores,store_images
where stores.store_id = store_images.store_id 
AND stores.store_id = 2;
```

Comment: Gag!  Learn explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I get to know